# What’s the most possible checkmates in one, but with no promoted pieces, in a position?

Tags: chess, puzzle-creation, checkerboard

What is the most possible checkmates in one without promoted units in a position? It must all be legal, of course. Promotions are allowed in the game, but the position is not allowed to start with promoted pieces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some asking on [Matplus](http://matplus.net/start.php?px=1556845598&app=forum&act=posts&fid=gen&tid=2280&pid=17268#n17268) a few weeks ago, here are the final records.

Without Promotions-43

> : [image]

The 43 Mates:

> Pd2-1, Pf2-2, Ph2,1, Nc3-2, Nh4-2, Qd4-4, Kf7-6, Rg5-12, Be4-13

With Promotions-47

> [image]

The 47 Mates:

> Pa7-1, Pd7-1, Ph7-1, Ne8-2, Qf5-4, Nd8-8, Be5-13, Rc4-14

Answer (score 5):

Here is 36, contributions given by:

> Bishop d4 moves: **13**, Rook c2 moves: **14**, Knight g4 moves: **2**, Queen moves: **7**

Picture:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I have 35, with the following:

> Nd7: **2**
>  Pg7: **1** (Q or B)
>  Rc6: **14**
>  Nb5: **2**
>  Re4: **14**
>  Qf3: **2** - 4 possible queen checks leave the rook at e4 unprotected

Picture:

> [image]

The secret to the moves here is:

> Double protecting all positions around the king, so that I could move any of those pieces to check without worrying that I was leaving a spot open for the king to move into.

Comment: @RewanDemontay You are correct. I have an e4 rook problem.

Comment: Well, updated answer for 36, while I look for a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that was the whole "thought both pawn promotions counted separate"

Comment: It's 36 if I put a pawn at d3, but that still blocks half the possible queen checks.

Comment: Well the, no point messing with this one unless I find a LOT more checks.

Comment: I've found some alternatives that go higher than the 36. I'll post one of those later. Still can't get to your total.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is an alternate solution with 47 mates that I found, originally posted here:
>   https://www.chess.com/forum/view/more-puzzles/diams-totally-puzzled-213-page-66-ndash-mate-in-one?page=2
>
> [image]

*Hmmm... I also just found out at matplus this alternate solution was first found in 1882... oh well! There's nothing new under the sun I guess...*

Comment: You can right click the picture, then paste it here